# Parse API and Show Output in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

So, I wrote a program that sends a get request to HappyFox (a support ticket web app) and I get a JSON file, Tickets.json.
I also wrote methods that parse the JSON and return a hash with information that I want, i.e tickets with and without a response.

How do I integrate this with my Rails app? I want my HappyFox View (in rails) to show the output of those methods, and give the user the ability to refresh the info whenever they want.

Ruby Code:

```
 require 'httparty'

def happy_fox_call()

  auth = { :username => 'REDACTED',
           :password => 'REDACTED' }
  @tickets = HTTParty.get("http://avatarfleet.happyfox.com/api/1.1/json/tickets/?size=50&page=1",
                          :basic_auth => auth)
  tickets = File.new("Tickets.json", "w")
  tickets.puts @tickets
  tickets.close
end

puts "Calling API, please wait..."
happy_fox_call()
puts "Complete!"


require 'json'
$data = File.read('/home/joe/API/Tickets.json')
$tickets = JSON.parse($data)
$users = $tickets["data"][3]["name"]

Count each status in ONE method

def count_each_status(*statuses)
  status_counters = Hash.new(0)
  $tickets["data"].each do |tix|
    if statuses.include?(tix["status"]["name"])
      #puts status_counters # this is cool! Run this
      status_counters[tix["status"]["name"]] += 1
    end
  end
  return status_counters
end


Count tickets with and without a response

def count_unresponded(tickets)
  true_counter = 0
  false_counter = 0
  $tickets["data"].each do |tix|
    if tix["unresponded"] == false
      false_counter += 1
    else true_counter += 1
    end
  end
  puts "There are #{true_counter} tickets without a response"
  puts "There are #{false_counter} ticket with a response"
end

Make a function that creates a count of tickets by user

  def user_count(users)
    user_count = Hash.new(0)
    $tickets["data"].each do |users|
          user_count[users["user"]["name"]] += 1
      end
      return user_count
  end



puts count_each_status("Closed", "On Hold", "Open", "Unanswered", 
                       "New", "Customer Review")

puts count_unresponded($data)

puts user_count($tickets)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. What have you tried?

Comment: You're right. I apologize. 

I'm pretty new to it. And I'm completely lost. 

I built the rails app, just a shell with views and models and authentication. And I wrote the program above. I just needed some guidance on how to integrate the two together.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new module in your `lib` directory that handles the API call/JSON parsing and include that file in whatever controller you want to interact with it. From there it should be pretty intuitive to assign variables and dynamically display them as you wish.

https://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/

Comment: Thank you! I will try that today and report back.
I will let you know what I come up with.